# Soldiers stuck as wounded?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In my barracks there are some soldiers that just say "wounded" without "(x days)", some of them have been like that for weeks without any change.

How can i get them back? is this a bug or something that i'm missing?

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Comment: Bleh seems like my save game has it's soldiers data totaly messed up. Now i have KIA soldiers in the barracks, soldiers disappearing after missions and other crazy stuff.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have tasted those alien rations :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have soldiers that show up as "Wounded" but lack a number of days until recovery, that soldier is, unfortunately, bugged.

A similar thing used to happen with SHIVs and was fixed in the 10/11 patch, so until Firaxis pass along another patch, you don't have any real options.